# Value of missing entry in a $5 x 5$ square

Tags: linear-algebra

If the square is completed with the letters A, B, C, D and E so that no row, column or either of the two main diagonal lines contains the same letter more than once, which letter should replace *? 
$\begin{bmatrix}
- &-& -& - &-\\
-& * &-& - &A\\
-& -& B& -& -\\
D &- &C& -& -\\
- &-& - &E& - \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

I am in doubt how to proceed with the problem. I have applied trial and error method and find the answer as $D$. But there must be some proper method to deal with this type of problem. Any clue please.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: You can complete, in this order; the fourth row, the antidiagonal, the fifth column, the fifth row. Then the only one option remians for $\ast$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space two below the given $A$ has $A,C,D$ in line with it, so must be $B$ or $E$.  If it is $E$ there in no place in the fourth row for $B$, so it must be $B$.  We can then fill in the fourth row.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
- &-& -& - &-\\
-& * &-& - &A\\
-& -& B& -& -\\
D &E &C& A& B\\
- &-& - &E& - \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The $A$ on the rising diagonal must be in the lower left, then $C,D$ complete the diagonal one way or the other.  We try one
$$\begin{bmatrix}
- &-& -& - &C\\
-& * &-& D &A\\
-& -& B& -& -\\
D &E &C& A& B\\
A &-& - &E& - \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and see the upper left must be $E$ and can complete the first column.  The second row then follows
$$\begin{bmatrix}
E &-& -& - &C\\
B& C &E& D &A\\
C& -& B& -& -\\
D &E &C& A& B\\
A &-& - &E& - \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
 and we are stuck for the third row, fourth column, so we must backtrack.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
- &-& -& - &D\\
-& * &-& C &A\\
-& -& B& -& -\\
D &E &C& A& B\\
A &-& - &E& - \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and we can see $D$ must go where the $*$ is.  If we trusted the setter to have made a proper problem we could stop here, but we will finish the solution.  We can fill the second row, the fourth column, the fifth column and finish by inspection.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
E &C& A& B &D\\
B& D &E& C &A\\
C& A& B& D& E\\
D &E &C& A& B\\
A &B& D &E& C \\
\end{bmatrix}$$